# isolating css in micro-frontends when using the same library twice

Tags: css, shadow-dom, css-modules, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have several micro-frontend react apps.
All apps are technology-agnostic. It's means that any app can have any library as dependency.
They are using webpack module federation plugin. Dependency will be shared if its version is identical in other micro-frontend apps.

Micro-frontends app are divided into groups: the Main micro-frontend app and Sub micro-frontend apps.
The Main app is a container for other Sub apps. Only one Sub app can be running at a time.

Our company has UI-Kit with react components. Library includes CSS vars, global selectors (* {/* CSS rule */}).

Sub apps can have our UI-Kit as dependency. If versions of UI-Kit will be different, one of Sub app can apply wrong styles.
Workflow (how it works): I open the Main app in the browser, webpack loads all resources of the first page of the Main app (JS, CSS, fonts). After that I open page with Sub app 1, webpack loads the resources of the Sub app 1 and inserts it to the document (CSS styles will be inserted to the head of the document).
Our UI-kit has CSS modules, but it is not enough, because the name of the classes are not created from content of the CSS rule. Also, the CSS variable may be changed in one of the versions. In addition, Sub app may not use our UI-Kit, but all * CSS rules from UI-Kit will be applied to this Sub app. Furthermore, two Sub apps can use the same library with different version and this library can use global or module CSS.

I need to apply full CSS isolation for every micro-frontend app.

Last time I tried to apply shadow DOM which support full CSS isolation. But one of library (cytoscapejs or its plugin) call the document.getElementById method. It returned null because an element which it is looking for has been in the shadow root. I am investigating this case.

Before that, I thought about adding a version to the end of the CSS modules classes for our UI-Kit. But it will not make the name of CSS vars unique.
In addition, I think I can't rename CSS classes of external library from my micro-frontend app build.

Also, I know that style-loader can allow to adding and removing style tag using "use" and "unuse" methods. I could be use it to prevent overriding the styles of the two Sub apps. But the mini-css-extract-plugin does not have this functionality.

I can try to use :has and :not selectors, but I don't want to handle many different CSS cases (* selectors, css vars, etc). I think it's a wrong way.

Comment: This is what native shadowDOM was created for. Your getElementById issue can be solved by creating a similar named method on the Web Component, thus not doing ``document.getElementById`` but ``[WebComponent].getElementById``, which (if needed) _dives_ into all shadowRoots. Note: If 3rd party libraries (or React for that matter) do not support diving into shadowRoots, the library/framework is to blame, not the native Web Component technology

Comment: I have one potential idea. I think I may render the Main micro-frontend app in the shadow dom. Other sub apps I will render in the light dom. If first sub app is active, I will turn off other sub apps link tags using attribute media="max-width: 1px"

Comment: I don't have time to test this hypothesis right now

Answer (score 0):

checkout [PostCss Prefix Wrap plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-prefixwrap?activeTab=readme) which prepends a selector to CSS styles helps to prevent CSS leaking from one Microfrontend into another.

In order to use the plugin install it and expand your webpack.config like this:

> npm i postcss-prefixwrap

```
const PrefixWrap = require('postcss-prefixwrap')
...
...
{
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    postcssOptions: {
      plugins: [
        PrefixWrap('#mfe_id_<appname>', {
          nested: '&',
        })],
    },
  },
}
```

Please adhere to the #mfe_id_ naming and add the same ID to the top most element in your MFE.

Advantages

- Easy to implement and works with nested css rules too.
- No need to worry about prefixing root(i.e html, body) elements as it
  is taken care by prefixRootTags parameter. By default, this option is
  set to false, indicating that the root elements will not be prefixed,
  but instead will be replaced with the provided #mfe_id_.

Disadvantages

- Requires using PostCSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

It won't work. Sub app will inherit the Main app styles.
Imagine that we have a box component in ui-kit and it is used in the Main and the Sub mfe apps.
HTML:
`<div id="mfe_id_main">
 <div class="box_hash" id="1">
 <div id="mfe_id_sub_app_1">
  <div class="box_hash" id="2">
 </div>
</div>`

CSS:
`// styles from ui-kit 1.0 
#mfe_id_main .box_hash {
 color: aqua;
 background-color: blue;
}
// styles from ui-kit 1.1
#mfe_id_sub_app_1 .box_hash {
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
}`

Comment: As a result element with id=1 will have expected styles: "color: aqua; background-color: blue;". But element with id=2 will have unexpected styles: "color: red; background-color: blue; text-align: center;".